# Can't scroll down, seems like the site is just a screenshot

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600|Lato|Montserrat&subset=greek);

body
{
  
}


.topbar
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
 background-color: tomato;
 text-align: right;
 height: 50px;
 z-index: 100;
}

.texti
{
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.linkur
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 8.5px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-color: transparent;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: darkred;
}
.linkur:hover
{
 background-color: lightblue;
}

label
{
 position: fixed;
 top: -2000px;
}

.mynd
{
 position: fixed;
 top: -50px;
 left:20px;
}

.navigation
{
 height: 96%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: tomato;
}

.logo
{
 position: fixed;
 top: -100px;
}

.hlid
{
  position: fixed;
  left: -2000px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 90%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.main
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
 background-color: white;
 left: 20%;
 right: 20%;
 height: 3000px;
 width: 60%;
}


.leikjatexti
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text2
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: darkred;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 48em){


 .topbar
 {
  text-align: left;
 }

 .linkur
 {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100px;
 }
 
 input {
  display: none;
}
label,
label {
 position: fixed;
 top: -27px;
 left: 5px;
  color: #0087cc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all .15s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 100;
}
label:hover {
  color: #ff7b29;
}

input:checked ~ .hlid {
  position: fixed;
  left: -50px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .15s ease;
}
li
{
 list-style-type: none;
}

.hlidlinkur
{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.hlidlinkura
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 7px;
 text-align: center;
 border-color: transparent;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: darkred; 
 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-family: "Sans serif";
}

.hlidlinkura:hover
{
 background-color: lightblue;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Main site</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Gru_main.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<nav class="topbar">
  <img class="mynd" src="project.png">
  <ul class="texti">
    <a href="" class="linkur">Games</a>
    <a href="" class="linkur">Profile</a>
    <a href="" class="linkur">My Cart</a>
  </ul>
</nav>


<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle"><p>&#9776</p></label>
      <nav class="hlid">
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li class="hlidlinkur"><a class="hlidlinkura" href="#">Games</a><li>
          <li class="hlidlinkur"><a class="hlidlinkura" href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="hlidlinkur"><a class="hlidlinkura" href="#">My cart</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>


<div class="main">

<a class="text2" href="Gru_login.html">
  <div class="leikjatexti">
    <img href="" class="mynd2" src="portal2.jpg" alt="portal" height="170" width="120">
    <h1>Portal 2</h1>
   <p>
    Portal 2 er leikur sem kom út árið 2010, leikurinn hefur hlotið gríðarlega góða dóma um heim allann,
     í leiknum þarftu að kljást við fjölda þrauta með byssu sem getur skotið hliðum inní aðrar víddir.
   </p>
  </div>
</a>

<a class="text2" href="Gru_login.html">
  <div class="leikjatexti">
    <img href="" class="mynd2" src="walking.jpg" alt="portal" height="170" width="120">
    <h1>The Walking Dead</h1>
   <p>
   viðmiðið í þessum leik er að lifa af og velja réttu leiðirnar til þess, í leiknum reynir mikið á leikmanninn
   til að velja rétt og fá rétta endann.

   </p>
  </div>
</a>

<a class="text2" href="Gru_login.html">
  <div class="leikjatexti">
    <img href="" class="mynd2" src="walking.jpg" alt="portal" height="170" width="120">
    <h1>The Walking Dead</h1>
   <p>
   viðmiðið í þessum leik er að lifa af og velja réttu leiðirnar til þess, í leiknum reynir mikið á leikmanninn
   til að velja rétt og fá rétta endann.

   </p>
  </div>
</a>

<a class="text2" href="Gru_login.html">
  <div class="leikjatexti">
    <img href="" class="mynd2" src="walking.jpg" alt="portal" height="170" width="120">
    <h1>The Walking Dead</h1>
   <p>
   viðmiðið í þessum leik er að lifa af og velja réttu leiðirnar til þess, í leiknum reynir mikið á leikmanninn
   til að velja rétt og fá rétta endann.

   </p>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
</body>
```

***strong text***

i need help with this code it doesn't seem to work when i try to scroll, i tried to put a height on the website, but then the site didn't scroll down it just staid in the same place, some words in the code are icelandic BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main div is fixed you should change it to relative in order to make the website able to scroll.

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked to change the postirion to relative

Answer (score 0):

All your content seems to have a position:fixed applied.

From w3.org - "An element with position:fixed is fixed with respect to the viewport. It stays where it is, even if the document is scrolled."

You should only use this on elements that you don't want to scroll, such as the menu.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you put `position: fixed;` on your `main` div. fixed means that it stays with the top of your view, so you cant scroll it away.

change it to `position: relative` and then you can scroll